# scan, groupjoin, or groupbyuntil?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

Suppose there are some Questions and Answers like in the diagram below. Answers always correspond to the most recent Question.

```
QUESTIONS: A     B      C        D
ANSWERS:     1 2         3 4 5    6
```

What is the best way to print out the corresponding questions and answers? Below is a solution I got working using Scan. However I'm wondering if there is a more intuitive way of accomplishing this using GroupJoin. I tried GroupJoin but couldn't get it to work. I'm also curious whether GroupBy or GroupByUntil are appropriate options (but also couldn't get these to work). Finally, is this a situation where I need to use Publish?

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var questions = new Subject<string>();
    var answers = new Subject<int>();
    var results = Observable
        .CombineLatest(
            questions,
            answers.StartWith(-1),
            (q, a) => new { Question = q, Answer = a })
        .Scan((a, b) =>
            (a.Question == b.Question)
            ? b
            : new { Question = b.Question, Answer = -1 });

    results.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine((i.Answer == -1) ? i.Question : $"  {i.Answer}"));

    questions.OnNext("A");
    answers.OnNext(1);
    answers.OnNext(2);
    questions.OnNext("B");
    questions.OnNext("C");
    answers.OnNext(3);
    answers.OnNext(4);
    answers.OnNext(5);
    questions.OnNext("D");
    answers.OnNext(6);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Expected output is this:

```
A
  1
  2
B
C
  3
  4
  5
D
  6
```

The more I think about it, the more this feature seems like LeftJoin behavior in the database world. I was also able to get it to work using code something like what you see below. For some reason, it doesn't work in a Console app. When I replaced the Timestamp function with my own Versioned function (that assigns incrementing long values) it worked perfectly.

```
var results = Observable
    .CombineLatest(questions.Timestamp(), answers.StartWith(-1).Timestamp(), (q, a) => new { Question = q, Answer = a })
    .Select(i => (i.Answer.Timestamp > i.Question.Timestamp)
        ? new { Question = i.Question.Value, Answer = i.Answer.Value }
        : new { Question = i.Question.Value, Answer = -1 });
```

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `GroupJoin`

```
var results = questions.GroupJoin(answers,
    s => questions,
    s => Observable.Empty<int>(),
    (q, a) => new { Question = q, Answers = a });

results2
    .Subscribe(i => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", i.Question));
        i.Answers.Subscribe(a => Console.WriteLine("  {0}", a));
    });
```

This produces the same output as your code.

Comment: Thanks! that works. When I tried using GroupJoin I think I was using Observable.Never by mistake instead of Observable.Empty. I'm not sure that nested subscribes are a good idea for output. I used this instead: `var resultsFlattened = results.SelectMany(i => i.Answers.StartWith(-1).Select(j => new { Question = i.Question, Answer = j }));`

Comment: I notice that "questions" is used twice in that GroupJoin query. Are you supposed to use Publish for that? Confused about when to use Publish or not.

Comment: I tried to work this all into my software. Seemed to work as you proposed in the console test app. In my real app, I had to do the .Publish().Refcount() thing on "questions" but not on "answers" to get it to work. Don't understand this part yet.

Comment: @JustinM - You should always publish if you find yourself writing a query that recreates subscriptions. But don't muck about with `.Publish().Refcount()`, do `questions.Publish(qs => { ... })` instead and replace references to `questions` with `qs`.

Comment: It's kind of hard to infer what you want to use this for in your app. Grouping with `GroupJoin` only to flatten with `SelectMany` seems silly.

Comment: I have a hard time with `Publish` as well, I'll defer to others on that. I do know that you only need it on questions, not answers, because there's two references to questions, (line 1 and line 2), and only one to answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dumb this down even more. 
I think the most simple answer is to just use merge and project both sequences to a common type.
Just looking at the expected output you can see that it is just a single merged sequence.

```
var questions = new Subject<string>();
var answers = new Subject<int>();
var Qs = questions.Select(q => new { Question = q, Answer = -1});
var As = answers.Select(a => new { Question = (string)null, Answer = a});
Observable.Merge(Qs,As)
    .Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine((i.Answer == -1) ? i.Question : $"  {i.Answer}"));

questions.OnNext("A");
answers.OnNext(1);
answers.OnNext(2);
questions.OnNext("B");
questions.OnNext("C");
answers.OnNext(3);
answers.OnNext(4);
answers.OnNext(5);
questions.OnNext("D");
answers.OnNext(6);
```

Results

```
A
  1
  2
B
C
  3
  4
  5
D
  6
```

Comment: That was my first thought. I'm guessing the question is representative of a larger use case. Thanks for IntroToRx, by the way. I would be lost without it.